# Не работает align-items

Tags: html, css

Есть вот такая фигня:

```
    <div class="main__block">
        <div class="main__text__wrap">
            <div class="main__text">
                <h1>Заголовок 1</h1>
                <h2>Заголовок 2</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.main__block {
    height: 91vh;
}

.main__text {
    background-color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.main__text__wrap {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Я не могу заставить работать align-items, хотя justify-content вполне работает.
Я новичок, возможно это что-то простое, но я в этом запутался, помогите

Comment: Если вы получили ответ, который вам помог, отметьте его, как ответ на ваш вопрос (галочка зеленая слева от ответа, ниже рейтинга)

Answer (score 1):

Вы неправильно написали html разметку для этого, align-items выравнивает элементы в контейнере (в моем случае элементы в контейнеры правильно выравниваются), а у Вас контейнер `.main__text__wrap` выравнивает те элементы, которые в нём есть, в вашем случае, это один целый элемент `.main__text`

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.block__inner {
 width: 100%;
}

.block__flex {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -o-flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 min-height: 400px;
 border: 1px solid red;
}

.block__element {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: #000;
 margin: 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="block__inner">
  <div class="block__flex">
   <div class="block__element"></div>
   <div class="block__element"></div>
   <div class="block__element"></div>
   <div class="block__element"></div>
   <div class="block__element"></div>
   <div class="block__element"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

А как именно Вы определили, что align-items не работает? С помощью align-items для .main__text__wrap Вы выравниваете .main__text. А если Вы хотите выровнять заголовки по центру, просто добавьте text-align: center

```css
.main__block {
    height: 91vh;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.main__text__wrap {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.main__text {
    background-color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main__block">
  <div class="main__text__wrap">
    <div class="main__text">
      <h1>Заголовок 1</h1>
      <h2>Заголовок 2</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```